# how to make a visual move or delete in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

I don't know how to make a visual move or delete. To make one I just do:

```
from visual import *
sphere (color=color.blue,pos=(0,0,0))
```

but that will just spawn a `sphere()`. How do I make it move or disappear?

Comment: This starts tomorrow: https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython1 This is what the doctor ordered to move things on your screen, and then some. ;)

Comment: yeah but... do i have to pay

Comment: I see... Obviously, it is not for you then...

Comment: i'm kind of a kid so...

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for a single move, then you can just change the `sphere`'s attributes`pos` (or `x`, `y` and `z`). To delete the sphere you can just make it invisible by setting its `visible` attribute to `False` and `del`ete it.

```
from visual import *

s = sphere(color=color.blue)  # 'pos=(0,0,0)' is the default
# Move the sphere to x=1, y=0, z=0
s.pos = (1, 0, 0)

# Now remove the sphere
s.visible = False
del s
```

Obviously when executing this code, you will see nothing since you deleted the sphere. If you want to do it when you click, try looking at [VPython documentation for controls](http://vpython.org/contents/docs/controls.html). I recommend using wxPython's GUI if you're looking for something a little more intricate.

Also, if you want to make an animation of the moving sphere, you could use a loop:

from visual import *

```
scene.autoscale = False              # Stop the scene from autoscaling
s = sphere(color=color.blue, x=-10)  # Create the sphere
for n in range(-100,100):
    v.rate(100)                      # Set the loop rate to 100 iterations per second
    s.x = n/10.0                     # Set the x attribute of s to move from -10 to 10

# Now remove the sphere
s.visible = False
del s
```